# Javascript JSON mutli group rows by value and objects (nested)

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I try for a while to convert my data with lodash .groupBy

It's a common case: orders lines with discounts (or not)

from this

```
data = [  {"order":"O1","headerO1":"559518","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-02T11:17:02.748Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":1,"item":"itemA","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.2}}},
    {"order":"O1","headerO1":"559518","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-02T11:17:02.748Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":2,"item":"itemB","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.5}}},
    {"order":"O1","headerO1":"559518","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-02T11:17:02.748Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":2,"item":"itemB","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":2,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.5}}},
    {"order":"O1","headerO1":"559518","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-02T11:17:02.748Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":3,"item":"itemD","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.4}}},
    {"order":"O2","headerO1":"660123","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-04T23:23:00.000Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":1,"item":"itemA"}},
    {"order":"O2","headerO1":"660123","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-04T23:23:00.000Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":2,"item":"itemD","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.4}}}
    ]
```

to this result

```
var data = [
{"order":"O1","headerO1":"559518","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-02T11:17:02.748Z",
  "detailLines": [
    {"linePosition":1,"item":"itemA",
      "discounts":
        {"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.2}
    },
    {"linePosition":2,"item":"itemB",
      "discounts":[
        {"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.5},
        {"lineDiscountPosition":2,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.5}
       ]
    },
    {"linePosition":3,"item":"itemD",
      "discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.4}
    }
  ]
},
{"order":"O2","headerO1":"660123","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-04T23:23:00.000Z",
  "detailLines": [
    {"linePosition":1,"item":"itemA"},
    {"linePosition":2,"item":"itemD",
      "discounts":
        {"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.4}
    }
  ]
}
]
```

It can be a solution with lodash, pure javascript (node.js) or another library.

So far I tried:

```
var grouped = _.chain(data).sortBy('order.detailLines.linePosition')
    .groupBy('order.detailLines.linePosition'); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped ,null,' '));
```

I think I might need a loop on groupBy?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: var grouped = _.chain(data)
  .sortBy('order.detailLines.linePosition')
  .groupBy('order.detailLines.linePosition')
;
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped ,null,' '));  maybe need a loop of groupBy ?

Answer (score 0):

Want to give this one a try?
Note that the reduce is from the right because I'm prepending the line items to construct the array.

```js
data = [  {"order":"O1","headerO1":"559518","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-02T11:17:02.748Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":1,"item":"itemA","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.2}}},
    {"order":"O1","headerO1":"559518","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-02T11:17:02.748Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":2,"item":"itemB","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.5}}},
    {"order":"O1","headerO1":"559518","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-02T11:17:02.748Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":2,"item":"itemC","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":2,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.5}}},
    {"order":"O1","headerO1":"559518","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-02T11:17:02.748Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":3,"item":"itemD","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.4}}},
    {"order":"O2","headerO1":"660123","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-04T23:23:00.000Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":1,"item":"itemA"}},
    {"order":"O2","headerO1":"660123","lastUpdateDate":"2018-03-04T23:23:00.000Z","detailLines":{"linePosition":2,"item":"itemD","discounts":{"lineDiscountPosition":1,"discountReasonCode":12,"discountRate":0.4}}}
    ]
    
console.log(
_.chain(data)
  .groupBy('order')
  .mapValues(details => ({
    ...details[0],
    detailLines: details.map(({ detailLines }) => detailLines)
  }))
  .values()
  .value()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great result Markus.For "order": "O1"."detailLines", we should have only one "linePosition": 2 with an array of 2 objects of {"lineDiscountPosition"... }. Another point, my fault in unit test "linePosition":2,"item":"itemB" must have the item (not "linePosition":2,"item":"itemC") : fix it into my first post

Comment: I simplified my code.
You should be able to group your `linePositions` by adding the same logic in a nested manner.